# Angular 9 Material Design Table Issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting this warning and my table is not displayed.

**Can't bind to 'matHeaderRowDef' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.**

**Can't bind to 'matRowDefColumns' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.**

**Dashboard Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DashboardService
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**Dashboard Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  public displayedColumns: string[];
  dataSource;

  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.createTable();
   }

  createTable() {
    this.displayedColumns = ['name', 'count'];
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(apiResponse); //api response is actual api response 
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

**HTML Page Code**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="count">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Count </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.count}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>

          <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Error Image: [image: Error Image]

But still, my table not show can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import in dashboard module and add inside imports[] the
MatPaginatorModule

Answer (score 0):

you need to import `MatTableModule` into the module where this component is declared...

```
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ... other imports ...
    MatTableModule
  ],
  ... rest of module declarations ...
})
```

Comment: in the same module where you're using it? are you using latest versions or earlier?

Comment: Yes in the same module I use. And Angular version is 9

Comment: Also, I follow https://stackblitz.com/angular/ponrlgyqnov?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts this documentation recommended by Angular doc.